# How to pass device traffic through ssh server

Tags: java, android, ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I am developing an application that want to pass my android device all traffic through ssh. My vps is ready and works very well as i tested it with other applications like [SSH Custom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.epro.ssc&hl=en&gl=US). I use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for tunneling and have input and output streams from both of VPNInterface and sshtunnel. But there is no lock. After some research i guess may using socket as proxy solve the problem. But i have no idea how to do that.Need your help and appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proxy tools e.g Charles, Fiddler

Comment: thanks. but can you explain about them or a link.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: i develop applications for android and app uses android network